# making sure that things work, period, ... -- I don't understand what "period" means here

Tags: meaning

> When you create more complex Web applications, it’s generally a good idea to have a
>   design of some kind in mind, rather than just attacking the problem using brute force. In
>   addition to making sure that things work, **period**, the most important consideration when
>   you’re building applications is making sure that they’re easy to maintain. There’s nothing
>   worse than going back and looking at an application a few months after it was written
>   and realizing that you have no idea how it works.

I don't understand what the word **period** means in that sentence.

Comment: The "*period*" ends the *sentence* (literally), and therefore also the discussion (metaphorically). So, the idiom means the same thing as "*no ifs, ands, or buts*". The speaker wants you to get it working, and does **not** want to hear a bunch of reasons or excuses later for why you couldn't.

Comment: *[period](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/period)* 2a. "used for emphasis to show that there is no more to be said about something".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Period' is an alternate name for a full stop - the punctuation mark that is used to end a sentence.

When either one is used in that manner, **it functions as an intensifier** by implying that the idea that came immediately before it captures all of the most important concepts by itself. There might be other factors that are worth remembering - in fact, this particular excerpt is mostly about a completely different concept - but they are *secondary* considerations.

In this case, 'making sure things work, period' means that the web application *must work*. If it doesn't there are no excuses, no mitigating circumstances - even if it's the most beautiful, efficient, elegantly-designed web application ever, it's a failure if it doesn't do what it was designed to.

Answer (score 1):

The word *period* (mainly used in the US English) means the discussion is over and you emphasize that what you said is *final* (from your side)

**However,** I'm not sure whether the *placement* of the word *'period'* looks natural in the sentence in concern.

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/period) defines it:

> [mainly US] said at the end of a statement to show that you believe you have said all there is to say on a subject and you are not going to discuss it any more

The example follows:

> here will be no more shouting, period!

Even I speak that word in the recommended way, at the end of the sentence meaning *final* (at least from my side).

But here, the sentence has *period* in the middle of the sentence, which makes *less sense* to me. I had hard time finding such example sentence from standard sources. I'll be happy to see if someone comes up.

If you ask me, I'd suggest 'comma' there over a 'period'.

> In addition to making sure that things **work, the** most important consideration when you’re building applications is making sure that they’re easy to maintain.

**over**

> In addition to making sure that things **work, period, the** most important consideration when you’re building applications is making sure that they’re easy to maintain.

In fact, this is really a strange usage of *period* word (in between commas) I've ever seen! :)

Answer (score -1):

Period = "full stop". End of sentence.  That is, the statement, if ended there, captures the essential idea.

Comment: But the sentence does not end there.

Comment: Much virtue in *if*.